# Fibonacci with memoization elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, fibonacci, memoization

I'm studying about functional programming and I made a simple fibonacci in elixir.

I know that isn't possible change values in functional programming and I made a code to make fibonacci with memoization, but the code is bad.
How can I improve this code?

```
defmodule Fib do
  def fib_memoized(0, memo) do
    {0, memo}
  end

  def fib_memoized(1, memo) do
    {1, memo}
  end

  def fib_memoized(n, memo \\ %{}) do
    if Map.has_key?(memo, n) do
      { memo[n], memo }
    else
      {n1, memo1} = fib_memoized(n-1, memo)
      {n2, memo2} = fib_memoized(n-2, memo1)

      value = n1+n2

      {value, Map.merge(memo2, %{n => value})}
    end
  end

  def fib(n) do
    { value, _ } = fib_memoized(n)
    value 
  end
end

IO.puts Fib.fib(1000)
```

In javascript is possible to make a High Order Function and save the "map" and update this one.

Ex:

```
function memoization(fn) {
    let memo = {}
    return function (n) {
      if(!memo[n]) {
        memo[n] = fn(n)
      }
      return memo[n]
    }
  }
```

Is possible to make something like it?

Comment: [*Memoization and Dynamic Programming*](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/imperative-programming-1.html#memoization-and-dynamic-programming) in the book *Real World Ocaml* talks about memoizing recursive functions. The knowledge translates into any language where a generic `memoization` function is desired. It even uses the Fibonacci program in one of the examples. Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 3):

Usually when I must store state in elixir I spin up a process to do so. In the fibonacci case an [`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html) fits in nicely.

It can be written like this:

```rb
defmodule Fib do
  use Agent

  def start do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{0 => 0, 1 => 1} end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def fib(n) do
    cached_value = Agent.get(__MODULE__, &(Map.get(&1, n)))

    if cached_value do
      cached_value
    else
      v = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
      Agent.update(__MODULE__, &(Map.put(&1, n, v)))
      v
    end
  end
end

{:ok, _} = Fib.start
IO.puts Fib.fib(1000)
```

Comment: I think this is an idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

The verbatim translation of the snipped you posted in JS to Elixir would be something like:

```rb
memoization = fn fun ->
  fn n, acc ->
    acc =
      if(!acc[n]) do
        Process.sleep(1_000)
        IO.inspect acc, label: "Just put... Need a rest... Sleeping... Zzzz..."
        Map.put(acc, n, fun.(n))
      else
        acc
      end
    {acc, Map.get(acc, n)}
  end
end

fun = memoization.(& &1 * 2)
{acc, _} = IO.inspect fun.(42, %{}), label: "Result for 42"
{acc, _} = IO.inspect fun.(42, acc), label: "Result for 42"
{acc, _} = IO.inspect fun.(3.14, acc), label: "Result for 3.14"
{_, _} = IO.inspect fun.(3.14, acc), label: "Result for 3.14"
```

Resulting in:

```rb
# Just put... Need a rest... Sleeping... Zzzz...: %{}
# Result for 42: {%{42 => 84}, 84}
# Result for 42: {%{42 => 84}, 84}
# Just put... Need a rest... Sleeping... Zzzz...: %{42 => 84}
# Result for 3.14: {%{42 => 84, 3.14 => 6.28}, 6.28}
# Result for 3.14: {%{42 => 84, 3.14 => 6.28}, 6.28}
```

It’s necessary to pass the accumulator through since there is no global state in Elixir. Oh, wait, there actually is!

I have written a detailed [blog post on how to memoize functions in Elixir](http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2017/11/23/idiomatic-function-memoization-in-elixir) with an example and ready-to-use code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Agent` works great as `memo`.

```rb
defmodule Fibonacci do
  @memo Module.concat(__MODULE__, Memo)

  def fib(n) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{0 => 0, 1 => 1} end, name: @memo)

    result = Agent.get(@memo, fn state -> Map.get(state, n) end)
    do_fib(result, n)
  end

  defp do_fib(nil = _result, n) do
    value = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    Agent.update(@memo, fn state -> Map.put(state, n, value) end)
    value
  end

  defp do_fib(result, _n) do
    result
  end
end
```

Similarly Factorial can be calculated with `Agent(memo)` as well.

```rb
defmodule Factorial do
  @memo Module.concat(__MODULE__, Memo)

  def fact(n) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{0 => 1, 1 => 1} end, name: @memo)

    result = Agent.get(@memo, fn state -> Map.get(state, n) end)
    do_fact(result, n)
  end

  defp do_fact(nil, n) do
    value = n * fact(n - 1)
    Agent.update(@memo, fn state -> Map.put(state, n, value) end)
    value
  end

  defp do_fact(result, _n) do
    result
  end
end
```